# Presenting a Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to present a NavigationController from a regular view controller. When I present the nav controller, all I see is the default navigation bar (no matter what I set it to in IB), which makes me think the navigation controller isn't liked right in IB. This is my code to open the navigation controller:

```
NavigationController *navController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavigationController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Here is my NavigationController header:

```
@interface NavigationController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

And navigationController is synthesized in the implementation.

In IB, I have a navigation controller that is connected to navigationController and the file's owner delegate. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

EDIT: This is what it looks like in IB:
[image: IB]
And this is what is looks like in the simulator:
[image: Simulator]

Comment: I don't think you're current setup is quite what you want. Would you mind telling us a few things about what you are trying to do with this navigation controller? Are you looking to add functionality to the existing UINavigationController, or are you looking to make a navigation based application (similar to Mail or Music) that gives you the back button and nice animation.

Comment: @Scott Rice I already have an application, it's just that I want to add a navigation controller. After I get it working, I am going to add a table view to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you currently have is a subclass of a UINavigationController. That would be what you want to do if you wanted to add custom functionality to UINavigationController (like doing a different animation between views). Since it sounds like you want to make a navigation based application, you actually just want to use the plain UINavigationController class. Here is what you what you have to do to get a UINavigationController set up with the content that you want. (I am doing this in Code because I hate having to set up UINavigationController's in IB).

In your applicationDidFinishLaunching, you want to add this bit of code.

```
// (SomethingApplicationDelegate.m)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Assume that 'window' is your main window, and 'viewController' is the property
  // that is automatically created when you do a new view controller application.
  //
  // Also, assume that 'ContentViewController' is the name of the class that display
  // the table view. This will most likely be a subclass of UITableViewController
  ContentViewController *content = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:content];
  [viewController.view addSubview:nvc.view];
  // This is the boilerplate code that is generated when you make a new project
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

This will create a UINavigationController and set up your table view as the content of that.  When you want to do the nice animation to a new view, you do this

```
// This will be inside your ContentViewController
// Assume that 'NewViewController' is the class of the view controller you want
// to display
NewViewController *viewController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
[viewController release]
```

This will automatically do the animation to slide to the next view controller, along with making the nice back button to bring you back to your ContentViewController

EDIT: To make the navigation controller show up as a modal view controller, this is what you do. Instead of using the above code in the application delegate, you do this.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPushed:(id)sender {
  // Assume this method is in a UIViewController subclass.
  //
  // The next two lines are copied from above in the Application Delegate, the same assumptions
  // apply about ContentViewController
  ContentViewController *content = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:content];
  // This is the magic code
  [self presentModalViewController:nvc];
}
```

Then, when you are done with the navigation controller, and want it to go away, you do this:

```
// Assume we are in some method in ContentViewController, or a similar view controller that is showing content
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewController];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need the navigation controller to show up when the app is launched. I need it to be modally presented after the user presses a button. How would I modify this code in order to do that?

Comment: It works perfectly and I didn't know it was that simple to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a navigation controller in your viewDidLoad?
so:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                           initWithRootViewController:view];
```

Answer (score 0):

navigationController.view is blank by default, you will have to put something there.

Comment: When I open the navigation controller in the simulator, it shows a blue (default) navigation bar at the top. Does this mean that the application isn't showing the correct view that corresponds with the navigation controller?

Comment: no that is expected, use [navigationController.view addSubview:someView]; to add a view, in a navigation project it starts automatically with it set up to add rootViewController.view.

Comment: When I add [navigationController.view addSubview:tableView.view] before the navigation controller is presented, it comes up with the table view on half of the screen with no navigation bar.